# Content related to role and user creation time

Tags: views, users, 8

I want to show content to the user which belongs to his role, such as taxonomy,
its creation time, or another user custom field. Is there any way to do this in Drupal 8?

To Clarify my Question:
I want to have a relationship between user.creation_time (or another custom date field user.start_time, user.end_time) and content.creation_time (or another custom date field content.start_time, content.end_time). So that i can say user a only sees content which has a start_time that is within his start_time and his end_time.

Comment: You should further define the relationship between role & taxonomy as well as the purpose of creation time and the custom field. Views might work, but right now your question is too vague to answer.